# Can I use an if statement to display the changes in my array (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make my function `displayValues()` display each value stored in the array `arrValues` each time it is called. The array undergoes a change before the second time it is called.

I am having trouble making the output `text` display the starting values in one 
 HTML element, and then the updated values in the second element. I am not allowed to have the functions return any value. At the moment my If statement only shows the updated array. I'd like to know what's causing the `before` element to not be shown?

```js
function start() {
    var arrValues = [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65];

    document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Array values before the update:";

    displayValues(arrValues);

    updateValues(arrValues);

    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML="Array values after the update:";

    displayValues(arrValues);

}

function displayValues(dispVals) {
    var i = 0;
    var text = "";
    var before = document.getElementById("before");
    var after = document.getElementById("after");

    while (i < dispVals.length) {
        text += dispVals[i] + " ";
        i++;
    }
    
    if (before == "") {
        before.innerHTML=text;
    } else if (before != "") {
        after.innerHTML=text;
    }

}

function updateValues(upVals) {
    var i = 0;

    while (i < upVals.length) {
        upVals[i] = upVals[i] + 10;
        i++;
    }

}

window.onload = start;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Updating array values">
  <meta name="keywords" content="arrays, display, update">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title></title>
  <script src="w8P1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <h2>Arrays</h2>
</header>
<article>
  <p><span id="msg1"></span>
    <br />
    <span id="before"></span>
    <br />
    <span id="msg2"></span>
    <br />
    <span id="after"></span>
  </p>

</article>
<footer><p>Produced by </p></footer>  


</body></html>
```

Comment: `if (before.innerHTML == "") {` ... because `before` is an element, so won't be equal to ""

Comment: Adding to @Bravo's answer, you should use `.trim()` to be safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `var before = document.getElementById("before");`

So before is the HTML span element, not a string.

You should compare the contents of the span:

`if(before.innerHTML == ""){...}`

Answer (score 0):

As most of the HTML elements don't have a value, you should use innerHTML.
Change the below line your code.

```
if (before.innerHTML == "") {
        before.innerHTML=text;
    } else if (before != "") {
        after.innerHTML=text;
    }
```